# How to put data to html but to look like excel sheet in django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, pyexcel

I have been studying how to put data from my excel document to the html, and I have found a way but it is bit tricky, maybe you can help me with this?

[(Link of documentation)](http://django.pyexcel.org/en/latest/#data-types-and-its-conversion-funcs) This is where I have been studying, but in this case it is defined what is a 'choice' and 'question'. Is there a way to do this without defining these? Tu upload random document and to load in html?

Comment: I can provide specific code.